# Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '1024x1024

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios11

I'm using Firebase Messaging in Swift 3. In IOS 10 was working. After updated my Iphone to IOS 11 stoped to work. Anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is the new change in iOS11**

Basically you need to provide 1024x1024 icon also as part of iOS11 so that if Apple wants can make small size icon if you have not provided any small size icon.

You will get warning while uploading to test flight - But interestingly it does uploads build on test flight without this 1024x1024 size. But to be on safer side you need to make it part of bundle to reduce chance of AppStore rejection.